# Accumulation points of cosine

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine all accumulation points of this sequence:

$x_n:=1-2\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$

and state a subsequence each, that converges against the accumulation point.

---

So the accumulation points are $-1, 1,3$.

1. $(x_{4k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}= 1-2\cos(2k\pi)$ $\rightarrow$ accumulation point $-1$
2. $(x_{2k-1})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}= 1-2\cos(\frac{(2k-1)\cdot\pi}{2})$ $\rightarrow$ accumulation point $ 1$
3. $(x_{2\cdot(2k-1)})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}= 1-2\cos((2k-1)\cdot\pi)$ $\rightarrow$ accumulation point $ 3$

Now they all are subsequences of $x_n$ but don't converge. They all have the accumulation point as their only value.

What am I supposed to do about the convergence?

Comment: `but don't converge. They all have the acumulation point as their only value`. A constant sequence does converge, trivially.

Comment: What is the precise definition of an accumulation point? If a sequence converges to $p$, is $p$ necessarily an accumulation point?